# Is there any word or phrase for negative bearing?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Features of a product matter when you are deciding to buy it.

If you know that it has a feature, say x, that you like, then that can motivate you to buy it. But a negative feature, say y, can demotivate you.
Thus, x has a positive bearing on your decision, whereas y has a negative bearing on it. One might even say that y has a negative bearing on x.

Is there any phrase or word for negative bearing of such kind. I can think of "negative pertinence", "negative relevance", "negative relation"? Are any of these any good? Is there a common way to express this idea?

Example:

> X has a _______ on my decision making whether to buy the product.

Answer (score 16):

I would use “[drawback](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drawback)”, meaning “an objectionable feature”. For example,

> I really like that car, but the low gas mileage is a huge drawback that I can’t overlook.

“Drawback” is less suitable for something that is a personal preference, like the color of the car, which might be something someone else would like. In that case, I would use “turn-off” as [pboss310 explains in their answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/212936/9161).

Answer (score 9):

Informally, Americans will say "turn-off". For example, "the phone doesn't have an replaceable battery, which is a turn-off for me". You wouldn't use it in more polite/formal speech though. If the issue causes you to fully reject something, you can use "showstopper".

Answer (score 7):

A **strike against** is another option (e.g., "the colour is a strike against it"), or **downside**, or even just a **negative**.

M-W defines *strike against* as follows:

> **[strike against](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strike%20against)** (*noun*) something that makes someone or something less likely to be accepted, approved, successful, etc. : *Her poor attendance was a strike against her.*

while *downside* is defined as:

> **[downside](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downside)** (*noun*) a negative aspect

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "deal breaker" is similar to "showstopper".  (But different in this way: a "showstopper" is an insurmountable problem because normally "the show must go on", whereas a "deal breaker" is not necessarily an insurmountable problem, it just means no deal is, was, or will be agreed upon)

You could also use positive and negative "impact" on your decision making process, like pluses and minuses on your personal "tally board".

While features A, B, and C positively impacted my buying decision, and features X and Y negatively impacted it; feature Z was a deal-breaker. So I walked away.

Answer (score 2):

I had a marked **disinclination** to dating her after I found out about her incarceration for assault.

I was **disinclined** to purchase the car when I discovered it had been in a wreck.

I was **chary** of pursuing that line of action; It could could be dangerous.

**Averse**, or **indisposed**  or **reluctant** could also be used.  All of these words have various shades of meaning.

In a slightly less emphatic statement, you could say you were **nervous** or **apprehensive** about doing something.

The absence of a safety switch on the machine provided a **drag** on my desire to own it.

I was **repelled** by the odor of the sweatshirt.

Comment: I added an example to the question. I want something meaning "negative bearing".

Comment: repulsion, antipathy...  All of the above imply a "negative bearing".  Averse and repelled are stronger word choices, disinclined or chary are less so, etc.

Comment: I want something that means it not merely implies it.

Answer (score 2):

A word not previously mentioned is **adverse**.  Although similar to **averse**, **averse** typically relates to a *person* whereas **adverse** relates to some *thing*.

Revising your sample sentence slightly:
X has an **adverse effect** on my decision to buy the product.  I am **averse** to X and therefore may not buy the product.

Both sentences tell us the likelihood of purchasing the product is diminished.  The first emphasizes the detrimental aspect of the product, the second emphasizes the buyer's perspective.

"Averse" describes a person's negative feeling or bias against something: Bob is averse to flying so he always travels by bus or train.  Many people are averse to purchasing upgrades if there is no backwards compatibility.

"Adverse" describes a thing's negative attribute or contrary nature: For Bob and his co-workers, skydiving was an adverse team building exercise.  Many people consider a lack of backwards compatibility to be an adverse selling point for tech gadgets.

There are also some words that may be better in certain situations, depending on the nature of "X".  Here are a few more alternatives that I did not see in other answers and when they might best apply:

X **discourages** you from purchasing the product (where X might be a person, such as your spouse or a negative reviewer, or cheap materials or poor manufacturing).

X **disincentivizes** you from purchasing the product (where X might be something that reduces a benefit of purchase, like a new tariff disincentivizing purchase of an imported good or the expiration of a rebate disincentivizing purchase of an electric car; or X could be some undesirable aspect that isn't specifically product-related, such as knowing you are supporting EvilCorp may be a disincentive to purchasing their product).

X **deterred** you from purchasing the product (where X is a possible negative consequence, such as "a lack of job security deterred me from buying a new car" or "fear of arrest deterred me from buying the illegal substance."

Answer (score 0):

**Bearing**, **pertinence**, and **relevance** all refer to the magnitude of the relationship between things. Something that makes you *not* want to buy a product can have just as much bearing on your decision as something that makes you want to buy it. "Negative bearing" isn't really a thing.

You can, however, say that

> X has an **unfavorable influence** on my decision whether to buy the product.

If you want something that sounds a little more scientific (or if you just want to sound like a statistician), you could say

> The presence of X has an **inverse correlation** to my decision to buy the product.

Comment: with x and y being things. We can say x has a bearing on y. Can't we say x has a negative bearing on y?

Comment: Bearing means it has an effect. If it causes you not to buy, that’s an effect. A “negative bearing” would mean _less than no effect,_ that it matters even less than things that don’t matter at all. You might say this as a exaggerated way of saying that you don’t care whether the product has feature X or not. But that is not what you wanted to say in your example.